# Charge Sony Xperia M4 Aqua with damaged charging port

Tags: charging, sony-xperia

My Sony Xperia Aqua's charging port is damaged, and I am unable to charge my phone. I have already ordered one for replacement, but until it comes I cannot use it. Is there a way to charge it?

Comment: [ EDIT ] No wireless charging    ... You could try plugging it into a PC with a separate usb and choosing charge only , Maybe it would work

Comment: None usb works, unfortunately

Comment: Is their a missing pin or anything that you can see in the charging port or on the cord, If you know anyone with a similar device you could just charge your battery in their phone ?

Answer (score 0):

As your phones charging port is damaged, and wireless charging is not supported for your phone you are left with just a single option to charge your phone.

- Remove your battery and put into other supported device that can
  accommodate your battery and charge the battery. This however would
  be challenging in your case as your phones battery would not be
  removable.

I would recommend you to wait for your parts to arrive and
   fix your phone.